# vector<T>::push_back is used on predefined constructor?

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I am here to ask if my perception is actually true. 
I originally thought defining `vector<T> v(size_t someSize, T init_value)` would call a function such as `vector<T>::reserve`, instead of `vector<T>::push_back`. I found some discussion relating to this here: [std::vector push_back is bottleneck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006634/stdvector-push-back-is-bottleneck), but this is slightly different in its idea.

Running some experiments, I notice that `vector<T> v(size_t someSize, T init_value)` calls `::push_back` all along. Is this true? I have the following report using `uftrace`(https://github.com/namhyung/uftrace).

```
     Avg total   Min total   Max total  Function
==========  ==========  ==========  ====================================
858.323 ms  858.323 ms  858.323 ms  main
618.245 ms  618.245 ms  618.245 ms  sortKaway
234.795 ms  234.795 ms  234.795 ms  std::sort
 72.752 us   72.752 us   72.752 us  std::vector::_M_fill_initialize
 65.788 us   49.551 us   82.026 us  std::vector::vector
 20.292 us   11.387 us   68.629 us  std::vector::_M_emplace_back_aux
 18.722 us   17.263 us   20.181 us  std::equal
 18.472 us   18.472 us   18.472 us  std::vector::~vector
 17.891 us   10.002 us  102.079 us  std::vector::push_back // push_back?!
```

Does `vector<T>::reserve` also call on `vector<t>::push_back` eventually? Is there faster version for `vector`?

---

The above was the original post. After some comments, I tested a simple version, and realized I was completely mistaken.

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std; // for the time being

int main () {
    vector<int> v(10, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

This actually results in the following, which doesn't involve `std::vector<T>::push_back`.

```
  # Function Call Graph for 'main' (session: 9ce7f6bb33885ff7)
  =============== BACKTRACE ===============
   backtrace #0: hit 1, time  12.710 us
     [0] main (0x4009c6)

  ========== FUNCTION CALL GRAPH ==========
    12.710 us : (1) main
     0.591 us :  +-(1) std::allocator::allocator
     0.096 us :  | (1) __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::new_allocator
              :  | 
     6.880 us :  +-(1) std::vector::vector
     4.338 us :  |  +-(1) std::_Vector_base::_Vector_base
     0.680 us :  |  |  +-(1) std::_Vector_base::_Vector_impl::_Vector_impl
     0.445 us :  |  |  | (1) std::allocator::allocator
     0.095 us :  |  |  | (1) __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::new_allocator
              :  |  |  | 
     3.294 us :  |  |  +-(1) std::_Vector_base::_M_create_storage
     3.073 us :  |  |    (1) std::_Vector_base::_M_allocate
     2.849 us :  |  |    (1) std::allocator_traits::allocate
     2.623 us :  |  |    (1) __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::allocate
     0.095 us :  |  |     +-(1) __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::max_size
              :  |  |     | 
     1.867 us :  |  |     +-(1) operator new
              :  |  | 
     2.183 us :  |  +-(1) std::vector::_M_fill_initialize
     0.095 us :  |     +-(1) std::_Vector_base::_M_get_Tp_allocator
              :  |     | 
     1.660 us :  |     +-(1) std::__uninitialized_fill_n_a
     1.441 us :  |       (1) std::uninitialized_fill_n
     1.215 us :  |       (1) std::__uninitialized_fill_n::__uninit_fill_n
     0.988 us :  |       (1) std::fill_n
     0.445 us :  |        +-(1) std::__niter_base
     0.096 us :  |        | (1) std::_Iter_base::_S_base
              :  |        | 
     0.133 us :  |        +-(1) std::__fill_n_a
```

Sorry for the confusion. Yes, the library implementation works as we expect, it doesn't involve `push_back` if constructed with `initial size`.

Comment: Elipses ("...") have a specific meaning in c++. Be careful using it in your questions and specially in code blocks as it can lead to confusion.

Comment: A common use case for `reserve` is to reserve once and `push_back` several times after. The two functions are not mutually exclusive, and in fact are very frequently used together.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you're right, i should have paid more attention

Comment: While the standard doesn't put much constraint on how that constructor overload works, I really doubt that any good implementation would do such without first reserving a size... What compiler/standard library are you using? What's your build flag?

Comment: @WhiZTiM I am using `g++ -pg ...`, gcc version 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6) (GCC)

Comment: Can you provide the code of your experiment? Is it doing anything else that could cause `std::vector::push_back` to be called? I can see in the gcc standard library source code that the constructor you are referring to calls `std::vector::_M_fill_initialize` but I'm not sure why it would call `push_back`.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Yes, you're right. I was mistaken. I posted my finding in the above. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Phew, looks like you answered your own question! I was extremely confused for a moment. Just hypothetically, I could have imagined some obscure case of `vector's` fill constructor using `reserve` and `push_backs`, but definitely not in the likes of high-quality implementations like those found accompanying GCC in the GNU standard lib. I would say, hypothetically, that it is possible for an obscure vector implementation to be implemented this way, but practically completely unlikely for any decent implementation.

To the contrary, this was almost two decades ago but I tried to implement my version of `std::vector` in hopes of matching its performance. This wasn't just some dumb exercise but the temptation was due to the fact that we had a software development kit and wanted to use some basic C++ containers for it, but it had the goal of allowing people to write plugins for our software using different compilers (and also different standard library implementations) than what we were using. So we couldn't safely use `std::vector` in those contexts since our version may not match the plugin writer's. We were forced to begrudgingly roll our own containers for the SDK.

Instead I found `std::vector` to be incredibly efficient in ways that were hard to match, especially for plain old data types with trivial ctors and dtors. Again this was over a decade ago but I found that using the fill constructor with `vector<int>` in MSVC 5 or 6 (forgot which one) actually translated to the same disassembly as using `memset` in ways that my naive version, just looping through things and using placement new on them regardless of whether they were PODs or not, did not. The range ctor also effectively translated to a super fast `memcpy` for PODs. And that's precisely what made vector so hard to beat for me, at least back then. Without getting deep into type traits and special casing PODs, I couldn't really match vector's performance for PODs. I could match it for UDTs, but most of our performance-critical code tended to use PODs.

So chances are that popular vector implementations today are just as efficient if not more than back when I conducted those tests, and I wanted to pitch in kind of as a reassurance that your vector implementation is most likely damned fast. The last thing I'd expect it to do is be implementing fill ctors or range ctors using `push_backs`.